# Cannot open unity project normally, error message: openProject projectPath:xxx current editor:',\n undefined

Tags: unity-game-engine

I use `2020.1.5lc1` version to open my unity project, but after I click the project in unity hub, there is no response, unity IDE didn't open. I checked log file find message:

> {"moduleName":"LocalProject","level":"info","message":"[ 'openProject projectPath: "xxx", current editor:',\n  undefined ]","timestamp":"2021-12-17T05:33:26.666Z"}.

Comment: never heard of an `lc` version .. what exactly is that?

Comment: Did you upgrade or change the previous Unity Version?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a known, and for now, unresolved issue that can occur when using the Unity Hub.

https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-doesnt-open-from-unity-hub.524320/

There's a bunch of suggested fixes from users:

- using a wifi connection only (unplug ethernet cable)
- reissuing the license
- reinstalling the hub
- using Unity without the hub - just as a standalone

And Unity is promising an update somewhere in the undefined future.

If you have a working older version you are upgrading from I would stick with that for now. But you can try any of the suggested fixes and work arounds.